# Convert Dotted Stroke to Fill in Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, stroke, fill

[image]

I tried Path > Stroke to Path but it just fills the whole rectangle instead of converting my dotted stroke into filled dots.

Is there any way in Inkscape to easily convert my dotted stroke to a fill?

If not is there an alternative application that does such which is free?

The SVG file's code is located [here](https://codeshare.io/aypQBe).
https://codeshare.io/aypQBe

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in Inkscape.  If I create a dashed stroke, and click *Path > Stroke to Path*, it works. [See screenshot here](https://imgur.com/ZbgdBrn)

Comment: I can't get your problem. Also I cannot recreate the situation in Inkscape. Can you explain a little more to recreate the problem. On Dashed strokes it works. like @BillyKerr  says.

Comment: @RanjithSiji I suspect there's something the OP has done that they have not mentioned.  Good to know I'm not the only one who can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RanjithSiji : So the problem was relative towards how my SVG was coded. The border was a custom border rather than dotted or dashed which Inkscape didn't understand. With a little Inkscape tweaking, it worked by using Path > Stroke To Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Affinity Designer, I can just go to Layer > Expand Stroke and it does the magic for me but I needed a free solution.

Currently, I would need to export it as an image (preferably 2 colors) and then convert the raster to a vector just to get the path's dashed border to be filled. Annoying and tedious but that's the best free solution I've come with.

**Edit**: So the problem was relative towards how my SVG was coded. The border was a custom border rather than dotted or dashed which Inkscape didn't understand. With a little Inkscape tweaking, it worked by using Path > Stroke To Path

Comment: This was indeed a valid question. If you're going to thumbs down please comment on why so.